# Pass empty map as arguments Getx

Tags: flutter-getx

For some reason I want to pass **company** model as **empty object** in Get.toNamed argument. I tried this way

```js
Get.toNamed("/profile?id=${data.id}", arguments: <Company>{})
```

received like this :

```js
 Company company = Get.arguments;
```

**But I got this error**

```js
Set<Company>' is not a subtype of type 'Company'
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass an empty object you need to use `.empty` :

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/profile", arguments: Company(id: null, name: null, etc: null));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your interest , I got this , The getter 'empty' isn't defined for the type 'Company'.

Comment: You have to define the empty property, add that.